# How do I align this table after "LITERATURE SURVEY" heading and not at the bottom of the page?

Tags: tables, alignment

[image]

the following is the code

```
\chapter{LITERATURE SURVEY}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
1   &   Bharat Bohara,
Sunil Maharajan,
Bibek ,
Raj Shrestha

    &   IoT Based Smart Home Using Blynk Framework    &   IJARTET 
Vol. 6, 
Issue 1, January 2019
   &   Node MCU and Blynk server are used effectively to connect electrical appliances \\
    \hline
2   &   Hiral S Doshi,
Minesh S Shah,
Umair S.A. Sheikh
    &   IoT: Integration of Blynk for Domestic Usability    &   9th Conference of inventive  communication (ICICT)
19 January 2017
 &  Provides an innovative way to connect home appliances together using Blynk.\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try `\begin{table}[!ht]`.

Comment: Why not try completely without the `table` environment, since you don't seem to want your tabular environment to float.